# Pivot table in pandas to count unique values

Tags: pandas, string, count, pivot

I have a dataframe of English words with French translations, here is a simplified version:

| English | French |
| --- | --- |
| to provide | fournir |
| to provide | fournir |
| to provide | offrir, fournir |
| to provide | offrir |
| to provide | fournir |
| to provide | offrir |

I would like to create a pivot table which counts the occurences of each translation, like so:

| English | French translation | Number of times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| to provide | fournir | 3 |
| to provide | offrir, fournir | 1 |
| to provide | offrir | 2 |

I have tried using the code below, but (1) it doesn't retain the French translations, and (2) there is only one row for each English word, whereas I would expect several rows, one for each given French translation.

```
df_eng_word_trans = pd.pivot_table(df_user_vocabulary,index='english', values='french',aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
```

| English | French |
| --- | --- |
| to provide | 712 |
| to argue | 521 |

In this example from my real data, there is only ONE row for "to provide", whereas I want several, with the count for each different French translation. I have also tried the following code:

`df_eng_word_trans = pd.pivot_table(df_user_vocabulary,index=['english','french'], values='french', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)`

But I get the following error:

ValueError: Grouper for 'french' not 1-dimensional

As a bonus, I also need to expand the French translations where there are two (or more) words and add them to the count, like so, but I think this is stage two:

| English | French translation | Number of times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| to provide | fournir | 4 |
| to provide | offrir | 3 |

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value_counts`:

```
>>> df.value_counts(['English', 'French']) \
      .rename('Number of times').reset_index()

      English           French  Number of times
0  to provide          fournir                3
1  to provide           offrir                2
2  to provide  offrir, fournir                1
```